# Error installing new software in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I cannot download and install and any new software in eclipse. I am getting the following screen .

[image: eclipse error screen]

I also tried configuring the proxy but with no success.
I am also getting a error window which says:

> Some sites could not be found.  See the error log for more detail.
>   No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/indigo.
>   No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.7.
>   No repository found at http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e.
>   No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/indigo.
>   No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo.

My proxy setting in Eclipse look like this :
[image: Eclipse Proxy Setting Window]

Comment: Are you behind a proxy at your location?  If you are you'll have to mess around with the proxy settings more.  These types of errors point to there being no connection to the internet.

Comment: @aglassman Yes I am behind the proxy so what should i do

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have chosen the bad link to install... Pls try another 
link and check your with eclipse version. They must be the same
Ex: Indigo

Thanks

Comment: I have tried all the links . It does the same with all the links .

Comment: What plugin you want to install and what eclipse you are using?

Comment: What link are you using?  Don't they usually have to end in /update  ?